# Cannot pass UIImageView between view controllers using a push segue

Tags: uiimageview, push, segue

I'm trying to pass a UIImageView from a Master View Controller to a Detailed View Controller using a Push Segue. Everything loads fine on the Master View Controller, and I've created a push segue using the UIImageView on the Master View Controller. Here's my Master View Controller -

```
class TrackMasterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var artistName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var albumName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfTracks: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var coverImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let firstRandomNumber = calculateRandomNumber()

        artistName.text = Track(index: firstRandomNumber).artist
        albumName.text = Track(index: firstRandomNumber).album
        coverImage.image = Track(index: firstRandomNumber).image
        numberOfTracks.text = Track(index: firstRandomNumber).track

    }
```

It's the coverimage which is being passed.  Here's my segue function -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "trackSegue" {
            let playlistDetailController = segue.destinationViewController as? TrackDetailViewController
            playlistDetailController?.image = UIImage(named: coverImage)

        }
    }
```

And in my Detailed View Controller, i have the following:

```
class TrackDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var albumCover: UIImageView!

    var image:UIImage? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        albumCover.image = image

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    }

}
```

Any help determining what the issue is would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing inside your `prepareForSegue:`, instead of using:

```
playlistDetailController?.image = UIImage(named: coverImage)
```

Use:

```
playlistDetailController.image = coverImage.image
```

Good luck!